# Yii2 assign model rules as per user role

Tags: model, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a model that is accessible to more than one user. Each user has a role. Below is my `model rule`

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['sim_id', 'meter_id','imei_id'], 'required'],
        [['sim_id', 'meter_id', 'installed_by', 'updated_by','is_latest'], 'integer'],
       id']]
    ];
}
```

In above I want the `imei_id => required` only when the role is `2`. User role can be taken out `Yii::$app->user->identity->user_role`

How can I do this?
Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [conditional validation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation#conditional-validation)

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['sim_id', 'meter_id'], 'required'],
        [['imei_id'], 'required', 'when' => function () {
            return Yii::$app->user->identity->user_role === 2;
        }],
    ];
}
```

Just remember it won't work on the client side (only server side).

Comment: Using `Yii::$app->user` inside of AR is a bad practice, it may be better to use scenarios-based rules and set scenario in controller based on `Yii::$app->user->identity->user_role` value.

Comment: Scenarios are not recommended anymore: https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/will-there-be-models-in-yii3/129681/4

Comment: @GabrielA.LópezLópez you are looking into the yii3 discussion , there are alot of things that are different when migrating from yii2 to yii3 but that isnt the question here the OP asked

Comment: But. This is a yii3 thread, but is also commented on other messages there that, even in yii2, is not recommended anymore, by Yii core devs